# Assoiating a screen-space distance to world-space distance

Tags: opengl, raytracing

I am trying to implement a volumetric lines shader as show in here: http://prideout.net/blog/?p=61. Basically, a bounding volume mesh is generated for each line segment, then the segment's 2 end points are converted into screen space and passed into the fragment shader. In the fragment shader, the screen space distance between the fragment and the line segment end points in screen space is calculated. That distance is used to shade the line.

The part above works. The problem is that the distance calculated above is in screen space. Thus, the rendered line segment radius is tied to its screen size. As in, zooming out or zooming in the camera does not make the line rendered appear to become smaller or bigger in screen.

How do I adjust the distance calculated described above (or any other method) to make the line appear bigger or smaller based on its distance to camera?

Here is a picture to show the problem:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glpjO.png)

When camera is zoomed far away, I should adjust the distance attenuation but I do not know how to calculate the correct distance attenuatiuon to use. For example, to draw a line with radius of 1.0 in world space and not 1.0 in screen space.

Comment: You could compute the desired radius in the geometry shader for the two endpoints, and linearly interpolate between them in the fragment shader. Not sure how you can calculate the two radii though..